# What does claw with their fingernails mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it the same as **pull out fingernails** like this thread?
[What does "pulling out one's fingernails" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193927/what-does-pulling-out-ones-fingernails-mean)

“I believe with the things that we have seen so far that it will end with a compromise between FIFA, UEFA, national football associations and the leagues and these 12 clubs,” Cortsen says. He adds, “However, I think we could see FIFA, UEFA, national football associations and leagues **claw with their fingernails** to protect their current position in the global hierarchy of professional football.”

https://www.forbes.com/sites/justinbirnbaum/2021/04/19/new-european-super-league-taking-a-swipe-at-champions-leagues-24-billion-annual-broadcast-revenues/?sh=4e36b66d1d05

Comment: Did you look up [what **claw** means as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/claw)?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are in a high place, and in danger of falling. You might be slipping. You will grasp anything you can with your hands. If there is not anything to grasp, in your fear you might use your fingernails like claws to slow yourself. This is a 'figure of speech' called a *metaphor*. The clubs are scared of falling down the ranks of world football clubs.

[Figure of speech (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/figure-of-speech)

[Metaphor (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metaphor)